# Question about python code structure, functions and calling functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, lambda, code-structure

I tried to create a function that does the following things.
(dont know if its worth mentioning but this function is invoked by another function)

1. connects to aws resources using boto3
2. gets a the number of messages available in an sqs queue
3. counts the number of ec2 instances
4. evaluates a set of conditions based on the sqs queue and ec2 instances and either do nothing or write to an sns topic.

Basically i want to publish to a message to sns topic every time the sqs queue is high and the number of ec2 instances which are digesting these, is low.

```
import os
import boto3
import logging
import types

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Create session and clients
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs')
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

# Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role ARN and a role session name.
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=os.environ['ROLE_ARN'],
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleFromCloudOperations"
)

# From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary credentials
credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

assumed_role_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken']
)


# Check the queue size
def sqs():
    queue_size = sqs_client.get_queue_attributes(
        QueueUrl=os.environ['SQS_QUEUE_URL'],
        AttributeNames=['ApproximateNumberOfMessages']
    )
    messages = int(queue_size["Attributes"]["ApproximateNumberOfMessages"])
    return messages


# Count the number of active ec2 instances
def count_instances(ec2):
    total_instances = 0
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[
        {
            'Instance State': 'instance-state-name',
            'Values': ['running'],
            'Name': 'tag:Name',
            'Values': ['NameOfInstance']
        },
    ])
    for _ in instances:
        total_instances += 1
    return total_instances

    print(f"Total number of active scan servers is: {total_instances}")


# Define the SNS Topic which will be integrated with OpsGenie
def sns():
    topicArn = os.environ['SNS_ARN']


# Evaluate the set of conditions
def evaluate_conditions(context, event):
    sqs()
    if messages > int(os.environ['AVG_QUEUE_SIZE']) and count_instances.total_instances > int(os.environ['AVG_NR_OF_EC2_SCAN_SERVERS']):
        print('False alert')
        logger.info()
    elif messages < int(os.environ['AVG_QUEUE_SIZE']) and count_instances.total_instances < int(os.environ['AVG_NR_OF_EC2_SCAN_SERVERS']):
        print('False alert')
        logger.info()
    elif messages < int(os.environ['AVG_QUEUE_SIZE']) and count_instances.total_instances > int(os.environ['AVG_NR_OF_EC2_SCAN_SERVERS']):
        print('False alert')
        logger.info()
    else:
        sns.publish(TopicArn=os.environ['SNS_ARN'],
                    Message='sameple message',
                    Subject='sample subject')
        print("Published to SNS Topic")
```

the handler is handler.evaluate_conditions

My question is how can i have some structure in this lambda function?
When i run the function i get a naming error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "name 'messages' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/mdc_alert/handler.py\", line 67, in evaluate_conditions\n    if messages > int(os.environ['AVG_QUEUE_SIZE']) and count_instances.total_instances > int(\n"
  ]
}
```

So it seems that i cannot use the message variable in the evaluate_conditions() function.
How can i make the "message" and "total_instances" variables usable in the evaluate_conditions() function?

I've written this function completely based on google searches, stackoverflow and boto3 docs since i don't have any experience with programming.

Is this structure any good, or does it need a complete overhaul?
Do i need to change the order of the functions, or maybe create a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that the `messages` variable is not defined. Your `sqs` function returns a value but since you're calling it in a void context you're not actually doing anything with that value. You can fix this by changing this line:

`sqs()`

to this one:

`messages = sqs()`

I also see some issues with the count_instances function. It's expecting to receive an `ec2` variable but you're calling it incorrectly from evaluate_conditions. You could either pass it the ec2_client variable or just use the ec2_client variable directly from within the function.

I suggest renaming your functions to more accurately reflect their return values:

```
sqs -> sqs_msg_count
count_instances -> running_ec2_count
```

Making these changes will allow you to refactor evaluate_conditions to shorten the if-then lines, making your code overall easier to read and follow. If you took all these suggestions into account, your code might look something like this:

```py
# Check the queue size
def sqs_msg_count():
    messages = sqs_client.get_queue_attributes(
        QueueUrl=os.environ['SQS_QUEUE_URL'],
        AttributeNames=['ApproximateNumberOfMessages']
    )
    return int(messages["Attributes"]["ApproximateNumberOfMessages"])

# Count the number of active ec2 instances
def running_instance_count():
    running_instances = ec2_client.instances.filter(Filters=[
        {
            'Instance State': 'instance-state-name',
            'Values': ['running'],
            'Name': 'tag:Name',
            'Values': ['NameOfInstance']
        },
    ])
    return len(running_instances)

# Evaluate the set of conditions
def evaluate_conditions(context, event):
    sqs_count = sqs_msg_count()
    sqs_average = int(os.environ['AVG_QUEUE_SIZE'])
    ec2_count = running_instance_count()
    ec2_average = int(os.environ['AVG_NR_OF_EC2_SCAN_SERVERS'])
    
    if sqs_count > sqs_average and ec2_count > ec2_average:
        print('False alert')
        logger.info()
    elif sqs_count < sqs_average and ec2_count < ec2_average:
        print('False alert')
        logger.info()
    elif sqs_count < sqs_average and ec2_count > ec2_average:
        print('False alert')
        logger.info()
    else:
        sns_client.publish(
            TopicArn=os.environ['SNS_ARN'],
            Message='sameple message',
            Subject='sample subject'
        )
        print("Published to SNS Topic")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried this out, but at first i got this error 
`running_instance_count() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

 I fixed this by adding self to the function like this `def running_instance_count(self)`. 

The Problem is now that i get this following error `errorMessage: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances'`

Comment: Oops, that's an error on my part. I used the global variable `ec2_client` inside `running_instance_count` but neglected to remove it from the calling code. I've edited my answer to correct this. FYI, in general `self` is used only for methods of a class; you shouldn't use it for functions. The new error you're getting means that you're calling invalid methods on the ec2_client object you're creating. I suggest looking at the boto3 documentation to figure out what's going wrong - specifically, how to create and connect an ec2 client.